# Folders in Grails Project Structure are not Displaying

Tags: eclipse, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've been working on a grails project and had the source committed to git.

Then I installed a new version of my IDE(GGTS 3.1) and pulled the project from GIT into my workspace.  The project runs fine but the Domain and Service folders are not displaying in the eclipse interface.

[image: Domain and Service Folders are Missing]

I've tried deleting and re-importing the project.  I've tried cleaning and compiling the project.  I've tried refreshing the dependencies.  I've tried restarting the IDE.

I've added classes to the domain and service folder and checked to ensure they are there but eclipse will not recognize the folders.

How can I get these folders to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

1. The Java model does not recognize the services and domain folders as source folders
2. There is some exception being thrown and they are being recognized, but just not being displayed.

Here's what you can do:

1. Do open type (CTRL+Shift+T). Do you see the missing classes there?
2. Open your Eclipse error log.  Any relevant errors?
3. Open the package explorer view.  Do you see the missing source folders there?
4. Run Grails Refresh dependencies

Edit your response above with the answers and comment below to let me know about it.

Comment: The workspace wasn't be built correctly because of some errors caused by dependencies not being resolved correctly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For me switching to Java Package View and then adding the "Domain" to the Build Path as a Source Folder
Then switched back and it was in Grails view as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the services folder not showing up. What I did was:

1. Right click on the project > Properties
2. Java Build Path > Source
3. Add Folder > Select missing folders
4. Ok

That should add the missing folders to your project explorer bar.